# SVG implementation in LWUIT

Tags: java, svg, lwuit

Can anyone tell me how to implement SVG in LWUIT application with some example code.?

Answer (score 1):

This will only work for MIDP devices, before Display.init() invoke:

```
com.sun.lwuit.impl.midp.SVGImplementationFactory.init();
```

Notice that if you use SVG images in the the latest resource editor (http://lwuit.blogspot.com/p/installing-latest-and-greatest-resource.html) it will work seamlessly regardless of SVG support since LWUIT's resource editor auto-generates fallback PNG's for unsupported devices and you can specify multiple resolutions for the fallbacks.